# split xml tag and group it into another tag in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

input xml

```html
 <root>
 <ref>
  <Auth-grp>
   <given-name>a.</given-name>
   <surname>aaaa</surname>
  </Auth-grp>
 </ref>
 <ref>
  <Auth-grp>
   <surname>bbbb</surname>
   <given-name>b.</given-name>
   <surname>cccc</surname>
   <given-name>c.</given-name>
  </Auth-grp>
 </ref>
 <ref>
  <Auth-grp>
   <surname>dddd</surname>
   <given-name>d.</given-name>
  </Auth-grp>
 </ref>
</root>
```

output xml will be:

```html
<root>
 <ref>
  <name>
   <surname>aaaa</surname>
   <given-name>a.</given-name>
  </name>
 </ref>
 <ref>
  <name>
   <surname>bbbb</surname>
   <given-name>b.</given-name>
  </name>
  <name>
   <surname>cccc</surname>
   <given-name>c.</given-name>
  </name>
 </ref>
 <ref>
  <name>
   <surname>dddd</surname>
   <given-name>d.</given-name>
  </name>
 </ref>
</root>
```

Can anyone please help on this for creating xslt 2.0? Whatever the tag either givenname/surname present at first position of ref tag in input xml, then surname should come first at output xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution but it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Auth-grp">
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 != 0">
                <xsl:element name="name">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="local-name() eq 'surname'">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::given-name[1]" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::surname[1]" />
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

This loops over all children of `<Auth-grp>` but only handles all odd (`position() mod 2 != 0`) positions (first, third, fifth, and so on).

Then it checks if this element is a `<surname>` or a `<given-name>`. And so it can choose in which order the elements should be displayed.

The loop itself is needed for the grouping within `<name>` elements.

Here you can try it online: http://xsltransform.net/ncntCRY